# Unison sync of sshfs mount - what can go wrong if the connection breaks?

Tags: linux, sync, sftp, sshfs, unison

I have a cloud storage server that I would like to sync with multiple computers. I have access via rsync, SFTP, or WebDAV, but no shell access. So I can't run Unison on the server. My first solution with lsyncd and cronjobs was not syncing deleted files correctly.

I finally came up with the following solution:
I mount my cloud storage via sshfs to a local mount point /mnt/cloud and use Unison to sync this directory with a local directory ~/cloud
I run unison on startup (via /etc/rc.local) with -repeat watch option. To make sure that it keeps running, I kill all unison processes and restart Unison with a cronjob every 2 hours.

This works fine when the sshfs mount is up. It seems that if the connection breaks, the sshfs mount is either still in cache or completely empty (which results in Unison quitting with an error).

My question: is this solution safe when the connection breaks? Or is there any scenario in which a broken connection to the sshfs mount may result in Unison deleting files because it doesn't find them?

Is there a better way to reliably two-way-sync multiple computers (including deletion of files) if I don't have shell access to the server?

Comment: This question *might* be better received over at [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/).

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I posted it at ServerFault [here](http://serverfault.com/questions/837819/unison-sync-of-sshfs-mount-what-can-go-wrong-if-the-connection-breaks), and tried to state my problem a bit clearer.